# SV Assertion: Check Signal is High for a particular State and does not change during that State

Tags: system-verilog, assert, assertion

I want to check If my Signal A is high as long as I am in the FSM 'FSM_WAIT' State. If A goes low anywhere in this State I should flag an error. The Assertion should check that A goes High during the state and stays High throughout.

I tried a sample Code somewhat like this.

```
        @(posedge clk )
        disable iff (!reset)
        (fsm_state==  FSM_WAIT ) && A |-> ##Duration A;
    endproperty : p_try  

Doesn't see correct to me though, please help. Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(fsm_state==FSM_WAIT ) && A |-> A until (fsm_state!=FSM_WAIT )
```

Comment: Thanks Dave with your response, I tried it and it seems to be working fine. Also, If I have 4 more signals B, C, D that should be 0, 0 and 1 respectively is there a way to check that in the same assertion . I believe I could do that with using && for each ? Any other way ?

Comment: `A&&!B&&!C&&D` or you could write `{A,B,C,D} == 4'b1001`. which ever is easier for you to read

Comment: Thanks for the Advice Dave. The intention was to make it more easier since those signals are to be check in WAIT State. But if either of those conditions are not true my Assertion would not be active and I would not be able to check A/B/C/D. Hence i should write separate assertions to check all. The Idea is to basically check all in the end but I don't want to lose the Checking by &&'ing it . Really Appreciate your advise.

Comment: Hi Dave, in your original response the Assertion will not be active if A is Zero in the FSM_WAIT state to begin with. It is checking that its not toggling in between but this Assertion will not be Active if A is low in the beginning itsels since the fsm_state is AND'ed with A . So how to check that my A was high as well when it entered ?